# Static factory methods with generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm having some trouble with generics in Java. I have a generic base class `A` that defines a static factory method to create an instance of `A` with initial values. I did this to set some initial values when creating an instance of `A` instead of specifying a constructor that sets initial values since it would involve calling overridable methods in the constructor (which is strongly discouraged).

```
public class A<T> {
    private List<T> values;

    public A() {
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setValues(List<T> values) {
        this.values.clear();
        for (T value : values) {
            this.values.add(this.modify(value));
        }
    }

    protected T modify(T value) {
        // Make modifications to value before it is stored. My real implementation actually does stuff.
        return value;
    }

    public static <T> A<T> create(List<T> values) {
        A<T> a = new A<>();
        a.setValues(values);
        return a;
    }
}
```

I also have a class `B` which extends `A` and specifies the generic type to use.

```
public class B extends A<Integer> {
    public B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the `create` static method in `B` to create an instance of `B` with initial items. When trying to call `B.create(...)` I get an error which reads:

> Error:(5, 23) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,E exist so that A conforms to B

So I decided to then try to define an implementation of `create` specific to the `B` class:

```
public static B create(List<String> values) {
    B b = new B();
    b.setValues(values);
    return b;
}
```

But this time I get a different error:

> Error:(8, 21) java: name clash: create(java.util.List) in B and create(java.util.List) in A have the same erasure, yet neither hides the other

While I understand what each error effectively means, I don't know how to get around them. How can I either define a static factory method on `A` that works with any subclass or how can I define a static factory method on `A` as well as a static factory method on each applicable subclass of `A` that overrides/hides `A`'s implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be no perfect answer here. There are several options that could make sense, but the details may depend on the application case. I'll list some options regarding the questions of **where should the static factory methods be, and what should be their names?**

---

1. Put them into the classes

This is what you have done now, but may have some caveats: The method in `A` creates an instance of `A`, and you cannot magically change this to be a `B` just by calling it "through" `B`. `B.create()` will still create an `A`, no matter what you do.

And creating a `create()` method in `B` will cause a name clash, as you observed.

---

2. Put them into classes that correspond to the classes that they operate on

The approach that [Tomasz Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684689/3182664) mentioned in his answer is not an uncommon practice: For classes that are called `ClassName`, there is a class called `ClassNames` that contains methods for creating instances.

<sup>It's so bugging me when the class name has no sensible plural, though...</sup>

As an example:

```
class Customer { /* With package-private constructor, usually ... */ }
public final class Customers {
    public static Customer create() { ... }
}

class PremiumCustomer { /* With package-private constructor, usually ... */ }
public final class PremiumCustomers {
    public static PremiumCustomer create() { ... }
}
```

This has the advantage that you can easily add classes that extend `Customer`, without affecting the existing codebase.

A minor drawback here is that you cannot use static imports of the methods, because they all have the same name, but that should rarely be an issue in real code.

---

3. Put them into one class that aggregates the different types

Your classes are called `A` and `B`, which does not convey the actual structure. But depending on this structure, it may make more sense to have one class with different factory methods (with different names) that indicate the specializations:

```
public final class Customers {
    public static Customer createStandard() { ... }
    public static PremiumCustomer createPremium() { ... }
}
```

Which of the latter options is "better" is hard to say. It also depends on the package structure: When the classes are in different packages, you cannot make their constructors package-private, which may be undesirable.

---

A note that might be important: You specifically asked about **`static`** factory methods. But the scenario that you described raises another question: **Who should call these methods, and how?**

Everybody has to know the exact type of the instance that he wants to create...

In general, when there is polymorphism and inheritance involved, `static` methods always fall out and can cause headaches. You should consider using a ("simple", non-static) Factory instead.

When you have this:

```
void example() {
    Customer customer = Customer.create();
    doSomeComplexStuffWith(customer);
}
```

then the implementor has to explicitly call `Customer.create()` (or `Customers.create()` or `Customers.createDefault()` - this does not matter here).

Changing the *type* of the elements that are created there is not possible.

At these points, you could consider to change the use of the static factory method to that of a `Supplier`:

```
void example(Supplier<? extends Customer> supplier) {
    Customer customer = supplier.get();
    doSomeComplexStuffWith(customer);
}
```

This way, you can use the static methods as actual *factory instances*, probably as method references. The implementation of the `example` method is unaffected by changes of the type here:

```
example(Customers::createStandard); // Run example with standard customers
example(Customers::createPremium); // Run example with premium customers
```

But again, that depends on how you intend to create and use the instances in the first place.

---

A minor remark:

> calling overridable methods in the constructor ... is strongly discouraged

This is true. But one could consider it as a corner case when you have a static factory method, and make the *constructor* of the class `private` or `protected`. Then, you can establish a contract and have far more control over the creation process, and make sure that there are no undesirable effects caused by the overridden method.

But in general, factories may indeed make it unnecessary to call overridable methods in constructor.

Comment: Thanks so much for a very informative answer. Exactly what I'm looking for and lots of detail explaining not just how, but why too. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jonathon I just realized that the examples that I described generally don't take a `List<T>` as their arguments. The answer by davidxxx may thus be closer to your particular case. (It's certainly possible to add this parameter in the examples that I used, but in the last section, instead of a `Supplier<Customer>`, you'd have to use a `Function<List<T>, Customer>`...)

Comment: No problem. I was looking primarily for an answer that explained at a conceptual level how to overcome my particular issue. I shouldn't have too much trouble translating between the types of arguments. My actual problem doesn't just use a `List<T>` either. I just created a simple MCVE to simplify the problem past any other details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're going the path that [Guava went](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fd919e54a55ba169dc7d9f54b7b3485aa7fa0970/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSetFauxverideShim.java), and now they [somewhat regret it](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1062#issuecomment-61347598). Namely, you're putting your static factory methods in non-final classes.

I'd like to propose a different approach: create a "
companion" utility class with a pluralized name (e.g. `SomeType` -> `SomeTypes`), and place your static factories there. Then do the same thing for your other types.

Thanks to such approach, you cannot (even accidently) obtain a type different than you expected (and now, calling `B.create` yields an instance of `A`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check out those links soon. I think your suggested approach is what I'll go for. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> How can I either define a static factory method on A that works with
>   any subclass

In this case why defining the method in `A` ?

> or how can I define a static factory method on A as well as a static
>   factory method on each applicable subclass of A that overrides/hides
>   A's implementation?

`static` methods and overriding are not things that fit well together.
You have to change your approach.

I would use one of these two ways :

- defining a static factory method in each class.
- defining a factory class that provide a factory method to create any instance by relying on generics, inference and `Supplier`.

1) Defining a static factory method is not complicated but you should be cautious about two things (the generic of the class or the absence of it) and the fact that a static method with a specific name and the same erasure in the class and the subclass produces a shadowing behavior in the subclass. Which is not very elegant and may be error prone.

It could look like :

```
public class A<T> {
    private List<T> values;

    public A() {
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static <T> A<T> createA(List<T> values) {
        A<T> a = new A<>();
        a.setValues(values);
        return a;
    }

}

public class B extends A<Integer> {
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    public static  B createB(List<Integer> values) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setValues(values);
        return b;
    }           
}
```

And use them in this way :

```
A<String> a = A.createA(Arrays.asList("hello" ,"you"));
B b = B.createB(Arrays.asList(1 ,2));
```

2) Defining a factory class that provides a static factory method.

```
public final class MyFactory{

    public static <T, U extends A<T>> U create(Supplier<U> supplierA, List<T> values) {     
        U a = supplierA.get();
        a.setValues(values);
        return a;
    }
}


public class A<T> {
    public void setValues(List<T> values) {
        this.values.clear();
        for (T value : values) {
            this.values.add(this.modify(value));
        }
    }
 }

public class B extends A<Integer> {
}
```

Now you have a unique method to create any instance of A :

```
A<String> list = MyFactory.create(A::new, Arrays.asList("hello", "you"));
B b = MyFactory.create(B::new, Arrays.asList(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very informative and helpful examples.

Comment: you are very welcome :) I just noticed that I mixed a little things. The interface is useless here. `MyFactory` as a factory class is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!